# Camel - split and aggregate exceptions

Tags: apache-camel

I want to send a massage in the form of csv file to webservice endpoint, split message to process each csv row separately, aggregate checked exceptions, and send a response with exceptions summary:

My route is:

```
<route>
    <from uri="cxf:bean:MyEndpoint" />
    <split strategyRef="myAggregateStrategy" >
      <tokenize token="\n" />
      <unmarshal>
        <csv delimiter=";" />
      </unmarshal>
      <process ref="MyProcessor" />
      <to uri="bean:myWebservice?method=process" />
    </split>
</route>
```

How can I do that? Response must be send to webservice

Answer (score 1):

How about using `<doTry>` and `<doCatch>` within your  logic? You could have whatever logic you want inside the catch, e.g. a bean to handle/aggregate/summarize the exceptions.

Something roughly like this:

```
<route>
   <from uri="cxf:bean:MyEndpoint" />
   <split strategyRef="myAggregateStrategy" >
      <doTry>
         <tokenize token="\n" />
         <unmarshal>
            <csv delimiter=";" />
         </unmarshal>
         <process ref="MyProcessor" />
         <to uri="bean:myWebservice?method=process" />
         <doCatch>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <handled>
               <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>
            <bean ref="yourExceptionHandlingBean" method="aggregateException"/>
         </doCatch>
      </doTry>
   </split>
</route>
```

Comment: Your solution implies, that I would have to operate on static fields. Remember, that I need to produce summary report at the and of route. Due to proper format of response, I need to throw WebFault exception

Comment: I had in mind to use a header to collate the exceptions. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found solution to my problem. I used aggregator and in case of exception, a collect it on the list in old exchange body and remove exception from new exchange:

```
public class ExceptionAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        Object body = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        Exception exception = newExchange.getException();
        if (exception != null) {
            newExchange.setException(null); // remove the exception
            body = exception;
        }
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(body);
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(list);
            return newExchange;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Object> list = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
        list.add(body);
        return oldExchange;
    }
}
```

The list is of type `java.lang.Object` because I collect original message too (in case of there is no excepton).